# How can I Save my file in the folder c:\ PCInfo, verify if the folder PCInfo exist, if not -> create it?

Tags: python-3.x

I made a python project , in the end I want to save this file in the folder , if there is no this folder the python create that, what should I do?

Comment: Please provide any code you have written to attempt it, and then we can help you

Comment: Further to @DeveshKumarSingh comment, please see here how to make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the question is  , Using Python, create a script for take information about BIOS, systems, HDD free space.
1)    Display menu
---PC INFO---
1. BIOS version
2. HDD free space
3. RAM
4. OS version
5. Exit
-------------------------
 Save your file in the folder c:\ PCInfo, verify if the folder PCInfo exist, if not -> create it.

Comment: What are wrong in my answer?
import shutil
import platform
import sys
import wmi
import os
print("Display Menu")
print("---------------------------PC INFO---------------------------------------");
print("1. HDD SPACE")
print("2. BIOS VERSION")
print("3. OS VERSION")
print("4. RAM")
print("5. EXIT")
choose = input("Choose an option:")
 
if (str(choose) == "1"):
    total, used, free =shutil.disk_usage("\\")
    print("Total: %d GB" % (total // (2**30)))
    print("Used: %d GB" % (used // (2**30)))
    print("Free: %d GB" % (free // (2**30)))

Comment: elif (str(choose) == "2"):
    c = wmi.WMI()
    systeminfo = c.Win32_ComputerSystem()
    print("Bios version:", systeminfo[0])
elif (str(choose) == "3"):
    print("Normal :", platform.platform())
elif (str(choose) == "4"):
    c = wmi.WMI()
    systeminfo = c.Win32_ComputerSystem()
    PhysicalMemory = sys.physical_memory("\\")
    print("Memory Info: %d GB" % (total // (2**30)))
elif (str(choose) == "5"):
    sys.exit();